# PG NPM Package Not Connecting to Localhost DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, npm

I'm having trouble getting the `pg` package working on my local system. I've tried to run the following:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var con_string = "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/documentation";

var client = new pg.Client();
client.connect(con_string, function(err, res) {
// stuff here
});
```

But I keep getting `TypeError: callback is not a function`.

Is there a setting that I need to change in order to connect to the db via a connection string? I have tried the username and password that I'm using  in `user:password` above on a database on my local machine and I can connect just fine.

I've also tried in the `node` shell in the directory of the project where I installed `pg` and haven't had any luck.

Thanks

This the error that I get from running the answer below:

```
$ node pg_test.js 
error fetching client from pool { [error: password authentication failed for user "jake"]
```

Comment: Isn't it very clearly tells you an error? "error: password authentication failed for user "jake""

Comment: I agree that the error is clear. I just don't understand why auth fails with a connection string when it works on the command line.

Comment: Because you sending "password" as password from conn string, and you send nothing as password here `psql -U jake -W -d documentation`.

Comment: it's the flag to prompt for a password. I guess I can try to see if it works without a supplied password and then just prompts me for one. I will have to check after work.

Comment: I just tried the connection string without the password and it didn't work. This leads me to believe that it's got something to do with the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from documentation at https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/documentation";

//this initializes a connection pool
//it will keep idle connections open for a (configurable) 30 seconds
//and set a limit of 10 (also configurable)
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
  }
  client.query('SELECT $1::int AS number', ['1'], function(err, result) {
    //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
    done();

    if(err) {
      return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
    console.log(result.rows[0].number);
    //output: 1
  });
});
```

Comment: I should've added that I tried copy and pasting this into a script in the directory of my project as `pg_test.js` then I ran `node pg_test.js` and opened up a browser to unfortunately see `error fetching content from pool...`

Comment: Because you have incorrect login/password - default user for postgres: postgres. This code WORKS. Check connection string. Try to connect throuth postgres client, etc.

Comment: The connection string works for the `postgres` user but I can assure that I'm using the password for my user that I can use with `psql -U jake -W -d documentation` and it doesn't work.